# How to avoid future duplicates in sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, database

I did a lot of question today about this and it might be my problem that I didn't clarify my question but I would love to improve in sql, right now
I'm in training and I'm Lost when it comes to sql... But I'm Doing great so far, I did a program in asp.net C# where the user can import excel files to an database...

My boss's want me to avoid future records duplicates, Exemple

Name      Age       City
 Pedro     12        Lisbon
 Rita      18        London
 Rita      18        London

How could I avoid That last Line be the same as the second?
there is a query that instantly delete duplicate in the moment that she is inserted?

Comment: HINT : `Unique` Constraint.

Comment: Question: Do you also want to remove duplicates which might already exist currently?

Answer (score 2):

You don't "instantly delete" records in such cases.  Instead, the `insert` simply fails.

If you want to prevent a duplicate of all columns, you can use a unique constraint or unique index (the former is implemented using the latter):

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_all_cols unique (name, age, city);
```

More commonly, tables would have primary keys and unique constraints/indexes on a *subset* of the columns.  In this case, it might be `name` -- although that is generally not as good as some form of actual id.

Comment: So I have to do a insert in asp.net and put that code in sql? Cause I want the user puts his excel file uplaod to data base and if he wants insert another records

Comment: no you have to change the table in the sql server, that's what the statement does. after that name age and city have to be unique. But that Solution coulb be problematic, because ibn Lisbon live more Pedros with the age of twelve.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an EXCEPT clause to your insert statement for whatever fields you need as a unique tuple.

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination(Name, Age, City)
(SELECT Name, Age, City FROM tblSource)
EXCEPT SELECT Name, Age, City FROM tblDestination
```